# Jolt JSON transformation is returning empty or null values except for the default values

Tags: json, apache-camel, transformation, jolt

I'm using Camel Jolt to transform an input JSON to other format output JSON, and my Jolt JSON transformation is returning nothing (either empty or null) value except for the default values. It doesn't have any error or warning on my code I will attach all my code snapshots here.

**pom.xml (dependencies)**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jolt-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**CamelRoute.java**

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:transformInput")
                .log("Received input JSON: ${body}")
                .to("jolt:classpath:jolt-spec.json") 
                .log("Transformed output JSON: ${body}")
                .to("log:finalOutput");
    }
}
```

**jolt-spec.json**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "inputField1": "outputField1",
      "inputField2": "outputField2",
      "nestedObject": {
        "nestedField1": "outputNestedField1",
        "nestedField2": "outputNestedField2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**TransformationController.java**

```
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TransformationController {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/transform")
    public String transform(@RequestBody String inputJson) {
        // Send input JSON for transformation
        String transformedOutput = producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:transformInput", inputJson, String.class);

        // You can return the transformedOutput or perform further actions
        return transformedOutput;
    }
}
```

I used the following input json in my postman to hit [POST]http://localhost:8080/transform

```
{
   "inputField1": "value1",
   "inputField2": "value2",
   "nestedObject": {
      "nestedField1": "nestedValue1",
      "nestedField2": "nestedValue2"
   }
}
```

The program runs well, it doesn't have any error or warning. here is my console log:

```json
23:44:23.393-04:00  INFO 29874 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] route1                                   : Received input JSON: {
   "inputField1": "value1",
   "inputField2": "value2",
   "nestedObject": {
      "nestedField1": "nestedValue1",
      "nestedField2": "nestedValue2"
   }
}
23:44:23.418-04:00  INFO 29874 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] route1                                   : Transformed output JSON: 
23:44:23.418-04:00  INFO 29874 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] finalOutput                              : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
```

Transformed output JSON is empty or null, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

It's weird bug! After I added **useHeadersAsParameters=true** as a query param it works.

```
.to("jdbc:datasource?useHeadersAsParameters=true")
```